# fn:transform running with default call-template invocation - no result-documents created

Tags: xslt, xquery, saxon

This transform test.xsl copies (for the purpose of a small test example) a directory of XML data by calling an identity transform for each recursively encountered XML file.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
version="3.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsi fn xs map" expand-text="yes">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   
   <xsl:variable name="currentStylesheet" as="document-node()" select="doc('identity.xsl')"/>
   <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
      <xsl:for-each select="collection('file:///mnt/c/home/oneD/data/translatable' || '?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')">
         <xsl:result-document href="{replace(document-uri(),'/data/translatable/','/translated/')}">
              <xsl:sequence select=" fn:transform(map {
                                   'stylesheet-node' :  $currentStylesheet,
                                   'source-node'     :  .
                       })?output"/>
         </xsl:result-document>    
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

However if I invoke it from XQuery with fn:transform like so

```
xquery version "3.1";
fn:transform(map { 'stylesheet-node' :  doc('test.xsl')})?output
```

none of the result-documents are created.

Is there something wrong with the invoking XQuery? I have never before tried this so it is my best attempt from reading the docs. Running on Saxon 10.3

Comment: Isn't `?output` supposed to give you the primary result and any secondary you would find by passing the result URI as an argument to `map:get` e.g. `let $result := transform(..) return $result('file://..../foo.xml')` or by outputting `$result?*` for all results?

Comment: The transform is being executed for the side-effect of the re-creation of each XML file on the file system in the new directory. I'm not  interested in the contents of ?output I just put it there to prevent a static error from occurring.  The side effect is not occurring when invoked from fn:transform -  that's my problem

Comment: The `transform` function doesn't write to the file system, it returns a map with the result documents, if you want to write them to the file system you need to do that in your XQuery code using `fn:put` or the EXPath `file` module. The `transform` function has a parameter where you can hook in a function to handle result documents to make such things a bit easier. But EXPath `file` or `fn:put` are not available in the open source Home Edition.

Comment: You wanna make that your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fn:transform` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-transform) doesn't write anything to the file system, it returns a map with

> one entry in the map for the principal result document, and one for
> each secondary result document. The key is a URI in the form of an
> xs:string value. The key for the principal result document is the base
> output URI if specified, or the string "output" otherwise. The key for
> secondary result documents is the URI of the document, as an absolute
> URI. The associated value in each entry depends on the requested
> delivery format. If the delivery format is document, the value is a
> document node. If the delivery format is serialized, the value is a
> string containing the serialized result

If you want to write result documents to the file system you need to do that in your code processing the map returned by  the `transform` function, for instance with `fn:put` or the EXPath `file` module.

The option map for the `transform` function also has a hook `post-process`:

> A function that is used to post-process each result document of the
> transformation (both the principal result and secondary results), in
> whatever form it would otherwise be delivered (document, serialized,
> or raw). The first argument of the function is the key used to
> identify the result in the map return by the fn:transform function
> (for example, this will be the supplied base output URI in the case of
> the principal result, or the string "output" if no base output URI was
> supplied). The second argument is the actual value. The value that is
> returned in the result of the fn:transform function is the result of
> applying this post-processing.

Note that neither `fn:put` nor the EXPath file module is provided by Saxonica's open-source Home Edition; there is a third party `file` module implementation on GitHub though: https://github.com/Armatiek/saxon-extensions